# Adding different bootstrap modal on jsp based upon condition using ajax in spring mvc and posting data through modal

Tags: java, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-mvc

I -> Hi I have different bootstrap modals in one page `general.jsp`.Modals are wrapped through `c:if` condition.So only one modal should be enable on general.jsp on click of button.For this I am delegating one ajax request to controller and adding Boolean variable to model attribute and returning it.

But the problem is that boolean variable is not appearing in `requestScope` because of which `<c:if test="${requestScope.isAddCategoryAttribute}">` is not able to execute and modal is not enabling to jsp .How do I handle such scenario using ajax in spring mvc?

2-> If condition is true and modal is enabled  , then I have to submit data through modal,  which is having its input field binded through `CategoryAttribute` entity , `CategoryAttribute` is a collection entity of a Category class.

But the problem is that , in `general.jsp` page `category` Object is already binded and populated in UI. And here modal is present in the same page general.jsp with different form tag.

So how would I handle posting data of collection  entity inside modal .So that it will persist the collection data of binded entity class?

Any sample code in controller side would be helpful to deal such situation thanks in advance

This is my Category class

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category implements Serializable {
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", targetEntity = CategoryAttribute.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
    (name = "name")
    @BatchSize(size = 50)
    protected Map<String, CategoryAttribute> categoryAttributes = new HashMap<String, CategoryAttribute>();

setter getter and many more attribute
}
```

This is CategoryAttribute class which is used in modal

```
 @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    @Table(name = "CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE")
    public class CategoryAttribute implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE_ID")
        protected Long id;

        @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
        protected String name;

        @Column(name = "VALUE")
        protected String value;

        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Category.class, optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
        })
        protected Category category;

    setter getter
    }
```

This is my `general.jsp` which is having already data populated related to category and it has button which is causing to open modal and submit the category attribute data

```
<form:form action="saveCategory" method="post" id="categoryForm"
                        modelAttribute="category">
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div id="general" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                                <div class="bodycontainer">
                                /** have some input fields which is already populated and bind with category object

                            </div>
                            /** this file have buttons which is causing to open below bootstrap modal
                                <%@include file="advanced.jsp"%>
                            </div>

                        </div>
    </form:form>

                    <div class="listgrid-toolbar-footer"></div>

                    <c:if test="${requestScope.isAddCategoryAttribute}">
                        <div class="modal fade" id="modalCategoryAttribute" tabindex="-1"
                            role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModelCattLabel"
                            aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <form:form action="submitCategoryAttribute" modelAttribute="category">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                                aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                            <h3 class="modal-title">Add Cattegory Attribute</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                                    <fieldset class="Key">
                                                        <legend class="ActiveDateRange">Key</legend>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label for="key">Key*:</label>
                                                            <div class='input-group date' id='name'>
                                                                <form:input path="categoryAttributesMap['check'].name"
                                                                    cssClass="form-control" />
                                                                <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" /> -->
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </fieldset>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                                    <fieldset class="Description">
                                                        <legend class="ActiveDateRange">Description</legend>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label for="key">Attribute Value*:</label>
                                                            <div class='input-group date' id='attributeValue'>
                                                                <form:input path="categoryAttributesMap['check'].value"
                                                                    cssClass="form-control" />
                                                                <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" /> -->
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </fieldset>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <span class="text-muted"><input type="submit"
                                                id="addCategoryAttrButton" class="btn btn-primary"
                                                value="Save" /></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </form:form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </c:if>
```

Advance.jsp

```
<div id="listgridthree" class="listgrid-toolbar">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <button type="submit" id="category_attribute" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                                    <button id="delete" type="submit"
                                        class="btn btn-primary disabled">Delete</button>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Comment: tl;dr what exactly do you have problems with ... it's not clear to me

Comment: @noobed Actually i want my modal to enable and pop up on click of button which is making ajax request to controller if you see my general.jsp page there is one bootstrap model wrapped around c:if condition inside which  variable(isAddCategoryAttribute) is not available in request scope. After that i want to submit the data through modal